# Hooking into cancel/abort event with octopus deploy

Tags: octopus-deploy

Currently we have a hipchat notification step as part of our process which lets us know if a release fails. Is there any way of detecting if a deploy is cancelled/aborted so we can display a relevant notification?

Thanks David.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Is it a scheduled deployment someone would cancel/deploy before it was run?
- Or is it a deployment with a manual intervention where someone would stop it
- Is your `send notification` step scheduled to `run always`?

After a bit of search found that one can alternatively [subscribe to audit events](https://octopus.com/docs/administration/subscriptions), which were added into OD from version 3.5, could be something considerable for the situation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alex. Yeah after posting the same question to Octopus support they recommend using subscriptions as you mentioned.